# compilation failed for package ‘XML’ on R

Tags: xml, r, compilation

I have a problem for several days I'm looking for the answer on the forums but I did not find it.
I want to install a  "XML" package on bioconductor, so I wrote:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
biocLite("XML")
```

And a part of the answer is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lltdl
collect2: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution 
make: *** [XML.so] Erreur 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘XML’
```

And I don't understand why R appears that.

I need of package "XML"  for an other package ("GenomicFeatures"). I can't install "GenomicFeatures" without the package "XML".

Anyone any idea?

Comment: "SystemRequirements: libxml2 (>= 2.6.3)". Do you have the libxml2 headers installed on your system?

Comment: Yes, I have installed libxml2 on my system:
Package libxml2-2.7.6-14.el6.x86_64

Comment: Are you certain libxml2-2.7.6-14.el6.x86_64 contains the **headers**?  It may just be the library.

Comment: I do not know about that. Is there a way to check that?

Comment: As @JoshuaUlrich suggests, one requires the `devel` version of the libxml2 library, libxml2-devel-2.7.6-14.el6.x86_64. Likewise for `libcurl`. But the error is about linking to libltdl, which suggests another missing dependency; my guess is that it should have been installed when libxml2 (or other) library were installed; are you using your OS package manager to install these libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is from the linker: `cannot find -lltdl`.

On my system, this library is provided by the [libltdl-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libltdl-dev) package. Other distributions will have a similar package.

Then again, on that system you can also say `sudo apt-get install r-cran-xml` to get a pre-built package.

Comment: I work on centOS 6 and the package "r-cran-xml" doesn't exist. The same applies to the package "libltdl-dev".   Is there a way to download it otherwise?

Comment: You need to navigate your distribution. I have built the package too at work on CentOS.  Try installing the `-dev` packages for XML as well as for ltdl. This is a widely-used package you should get to work as it builds reliably for numerous other users.  But you need to the tools sorted out.

Comment: Great. Now please consider following StackOverflow custom and "accept" (click on tick mark) and/or "upvote" (click on arrow) this question if you feel it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on CentOS 6, to get `lltdl` you need to install `libtool-ltdl-devel`:

```
sudo yum install -y libtool-ltdl-devel
```